# How can I get my button to work with the rest of my javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make a button that makes drop down menu pop up. I want the user to be able to toggle the pop up menu off by either pressing the button again or by clicking outside of the menu. With my current code I can use the button to open the drop down menu, but the button stops working afterwords. Exiting the menu by clicking outside of the menu works just fine. How can I get my button to stay working after I open the menu

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{ margin:0px; background:#999; }
div#topbar > #sections_panel{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:550px;
    background:#000;
    top:60px;
    left:0px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:10000;
}
div#topbar > #sections_panel > div{
    background:#333;
    padding:20px;
    height:238px;
    margin:10px;
    color:#FC0;
}
</style>
<script>
function toggleNavPanel(x){
    var panel = document.getElementById(x), maxH="300px";
    var box = document.getElementById('sections_panel')

  if(panel.style.height == maxH){
      panel.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        panel.style.height = maxH;
    }

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
        if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode !=box){
             panel.style.height = "0px";

        }
});
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div id="sections_btn_holder">
    <button onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')">Navigator <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sections_panel">
    <div>
      Try adding things like more child div containers, links, buttons, menus, pictures, paragraphs, videos, etc... This area can display way more than just menu buttons or links. You will see a lot of modern sites even adding graphics, icons, animations and images to their drop down menus nowadays. So get creative partner.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

New code for multiple buttons (for anyone interested in doing multiple buttons):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{ margin:0px; background:#999; }
div#topbar > #sections_panel{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:550px;
    background:#000;
    top:200px;
    left:0px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:10000;
}
div#topbar > #sections_panel > div{
    background:#333;
    padding:20px;
    height:238px;
    margin:10px;
    color:#FC0;
}

div#topbar1 > #sections_panel1{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:550px;
    background:#000;
    top:250px;
    left:0px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:10000;
}
div#topbar1 > #sections_panel1 > div{
    background:#333;
    padding:20px;
    height:238px;
    margin:10px;
    color:#FC0;
}
</style>
<script>
function toggleNavPanel(dropDivId, height, btnId){
    var panel = document.getElementById(dropDivId), maxH= height, nav = btnId;
  if(panel.style.height == maxH){
      panel.style.height = "0px";
    } else {
        panel.style.height = maxH;
    }
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
        if(event.target != panel && event.target.parentNode !=panel && event.target.id != nav ){
             panel.style.height = "0px"; 
        }
});
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div id="sections_btn_holder">
    <button id="nav2" onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel', '300px','nav2')">Navigator &#9662;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="sections_panel">
    <div>
        hahahahaha
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="topbar1">
  <div id="logo1">LOGO</div>
  <div id="sections_btn_holder1">
    <button id="nav1" onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel1', '300px','nav1')">Navigator &#9662;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="sections_panel1">
    <div>
        hahahahaha
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**
When you click the button, *both* events are fired.

- The MouseUp event handler is called first, closing the menu.
- The OnClick event handler is called next, detecting that the menu is closed, consequently opening it again.

With today's browsers, this all happens without a glitch; seemingly nothing happened.

**Solution:**
Add a condition to the MouseUp event handler:

```
if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode !=box && event.target.tagName != "BUTTON"){
```

or

```
if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box && event.target !== nav){
```

For the latter approach to work, you need to give the button an ID:

```
<button id="nav" onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')">Navigator <span id="navarrow">&#9662;</span></button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote you to show my appreciation, but they don't count yet, so here's a happy face instead :D. Very Helpful!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. If it does _not_ solve your problem, then please let me know, so I can work on that.

Comment: Oh I did not know I could "accept" an answer. Yes, it did solve my problem , Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Ruud, the button part fixed my code for a single button, but now that I added another button there's a new issue. I can click on my first button and the menu opens up, but when I click on the second button the first menu does not close, so then I have two menus open. I thought maybe it happened because it can't distinguish between the two buttons, so I put an id on both and did it the second way you suggested, but that puts me back to my original problem. I'm going to re-edit the post so you can see my new code.